# Remove category slug from url and Redirect URL slug

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing a problem in which category slug is causing problem:

```
example.com/category/abc
```

I want it to be redirected to: domain.com/abc

My current `.htaccess` file is as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ catlinks.php?id=$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ show.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Please note that the current url is also being redirected from `example.com/category/catlinks.php?id=4` to `example.com/category/abc`

Here is the code that is changing the id to slug in category:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM post_category WHERE categorySlug = :categorySlug');
$stmt->execute(array(':categorySlug' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Code for single article

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE articleSlug = :articleSlug');
$stmt->execute(array(':articleSlug' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Category and article slug are stored in database.

Looking forward to an answer.

Comment: What is stopping you from redirecting `/category/abc` to `/abc`? Although if `category` is removed then obviously your existing rule is not going to work. "Please note that the current url is also being redirected from domain.com/category/catlinks.php?id=4 to domain.com/category/abc" - where is this being performed?

Comment: Added the slug code that was missing. 

ALso, I can't firgure out how to remove that category slug from permalink using htaccess code (beginner in htaccess) :)